# Migrate customers to Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

First of all thank you for taking a look the the problem that I'm facing today.

I'm currently working on a project that includes prestashop 1.7. What I'm trying to do is as following. I want to migrate my prestashop 1.6.11 to 1.7. Now I know that there is currently no support on this option but I really want to upgrade it for some important reasons. I did migrate the customers and there invoices to 1.7 but when I try log in on the new website nothing happens(I made a test account on 1.6). There is no error or anything but the page refreshes and that's it. I did look on multiple websites for a solution but that came out blank.

Is what I am trying to do even possible or does anybody have an idea where to look or what to change.

Hope that somebody has a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a _COOKIE_KEY_ in PrestaShop that is used to encrypt the password before saving them to the database. The _COOKIE_KEY_ for each PrestaShop installation. The _COOKIE_KEY_ is unique for each and every PrestaShop installation.

You can find the _COOKIE_KEY_ in following paths:

/app/config/parameters.php (in PrestaShop 1.7)
/config/settings.inc.php (in PrestaShop 1.6)

You should set the passwords for your users on your new PrestaShop 1.7 store again using the updated _COOKIE_KEY_

You can take a look at Tools::encrypt() function to find out how it is encrypted.

Note: This _COOKIE_KEY_ is called 'secret' in PrestaShop 1.7

Comment: Do I have to migrate all the customers first or just change to the new _COOKIEKEY_

Answer (score 1):

Migrating from Prestashop 1.6 to Prestashop 1.7 requires you to use Prestashop Migrator. This is its Github project: https://github.com/ets-soft/prestashop-migrator-free-version

The steps are very simple: 
Just download [Prestashop Migrator (ets_pres2presfree.zip)](https://github.com/ets-soft/prestashop-migrator-free-version/raw/master/ets_pres2presfree.zip) then follow 3 simple steps below

Step 1: Install [Prestashop connector](https://github.com/ets-soft/prestashop-migrator-free-version/raw/master/plugins/ets_pres2presconnector.zip) on the source website (your old website.)

Step 2: Install a fresh Prestashop 1.7 website (target website) then install [Prestashop migrator](https://github.com/ets-soft/prestashop-migrator-free-version/raw/master/ets_pres2presfree.zip) on the website you just installed.

Step 3: Start migrating your data from the source website to target website. Wait a few minutes and enjoy your new Prestashop 1.7 website.